# How to find the union of any progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Here is an answer to find the union of two arithmetic progression.
[How to find a general formula for union of two arithmetic progressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327683/942553)

But, is there a formula to find the union of the sets of two non-arithmetic, non-geometric progressions?

For example,the union of $ {2^n}$ and $ \frac{2^n - 1}{3}$ ?

By union, I mean the union of two sets like if the progressions are 2n(even numbers) and 2n+1 (odd numbers) then the union would be n (whole numbers)

If progressions are

P1 = {0,2,4,6,...} and

P2 = {1,3,5,7,...}

Then the union

$ P_1 \space U \space P_2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,..} $

Comment: Can you define in the question what you mean by the union, to have a self contained question? Thanks.

Comment: The linked question had the progression strictly increasing

Comment: @Henry Yes, but isn't that the same for 2^n ? If not , what difference does it make? Is it impossible to find the union of set of non-increasing progressions?

Comment: How does this union work if $P = (0,1,2,3,\ldots)$ and $Q=(0,2,4,\ldots)$? Do you get $P \cup Q = (0,0,1,2,2,4,3,6,\ldots)$?

Comment: @gt6989b   Doesn't the Union operation automatically removes the duplicates? >>"For example, if A = {1, 3, 5, 7} and B = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7} then A ∪ B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}" From wikipedia

Comment: There is not in general, though may be in your particular example such as $\frac12\left(\left(\left(3+\sqrt 8\right) +(-1)^n\left(3-\sqrt 8\right)\right)2^{\frac n2}-\left(1-(-1)^n\right)\right)$ if you ignore the initial terms

Comment: @Henry Is this derived? If yes, can you link me to a derivation please?

Comment: It just takes the two sequences (which after the start just alternate) and uses the alternating  $(-1)^n$ to combine them -  I have not checked it so there may be errors

Comment: @Henry Ok, thanks