# How to find the formula of the union of two sets that are defined by linear functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$S = \{ax + b | x \in \Bbb N \}$$
$$T = \{gx + k | x \in \Bbb N \}$$
$$V = S \cup T$$
$$V_n = ? \quad\text{sorted in ascending order}$$
For example,
$$S = \{3x + 2 | x \in \Bbb N \} = \{2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, ...\}$$
$$T = \{2x + 4 | x \in \Bbb N \} = \{4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, ...\}$$
$$V = S \cup T  = \{2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, ...\}$$
How do I find the formula for $V_n$ given the formula for $S_n$ and $T_n$? Would it also be a linear function? Is there any kind of 'formula for the formula'?

Comment: Short answer: no such formula. You are looking at a union of arithmetic progressions. The least common multiple of $a$ and $g$ will be the period of the union. The remainders mod $6$ repeat in your example.

Comment: It is obviously not linear. [How to find a general formula for union of two arithmetic progressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327683/how-to-find-a-general-formula-for-union-of-two-arithmetic-progressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Ethan Bolker says there is no such formula, he means there is no *nice* formula. It isn't linear, it isn't geometric. It isn't anything you can get performing a few multiplications, additions, divisions, and subtractions. Instead it requires a decision tree to find.

We can approach the problem by turning it around. For some integer $k>2$, how many elements of $V$ are $\le k$? This is more tractable as it is solved easily for $S$ and $T$, and also for
$$U = S\cap T = \{8, 14, 20, 26, \dots\} = \{6x + 8\mid x \in \Bbb N\}$$
To understand why $U$ is an arithmetic progression and has that formula, consult the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Label $V^k = \{x \in V\mid x \le k\}$, and similarly for the other sets. Then $$|S^k| = \left\lfloor \frac{k-2}3\right\rfloor+1\\|T^k| = \left\lfloor \frac{k-4}2\right\rfloor+1\\|U^k| = \left\lfloor \frac{k-8}6\right\rfloor+1$$
where $|A|$ denotes the number of elements in the set $A$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\le x$. Now for sets $A, B$, it is always true that $$|A| + |B| = |A\cup B| + |A \cap B|$$
Thus $$|V^k| = |S^k|+|T^k|-|U^k|$$ $$|V^k| = \left\lfloor \frac{k-2}3\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k-4}2\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{k-8}6\right\rfloor+1$$
If $k\in V$ and $n = |V^k|-1$, then $V_n = k$ (assuming that the indexing starts with $n = 0$). Thus $$n = \left\lfloor \frac{k-2}3\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k-4}2\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{k-8}6\right\rfloor$$

Note that $k>2$ is in $S$ if and only if it is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, is in $T$ if and only if it is even, and is only in $U$ if it is congruent to $2$ modulo $6$. So

- if $k = 6m$, then $k \in T$, but not in $S$ or $U$. If $n = (2m-1) + (3m-2) - (m - 2) = 4m-1$, then $V_n = k = \frac{3n+3}2$.
- if $k = 6m+1$, then $k$ is not in any set.
- if $k = 6m+2$, then $k$ is in all three sets. $n=(2m) + (3m-1) - (m-1) = 4m$ gives $V_n = k= \frac {3n + 2}2$.
- if $k = 6m+3$, then $k$ is not in any set.
- if $k = 6m+4$, then $k$ is in $T$, but not $S$ or $U$. $n = (2m) + (3m) - (m-1) = 4m + 1$ gives $V_n = k = \frac{3n+5}2$.
- if $k = 6m+5$, then $k$ is not in $T$ or $U$, but is in $S$. $n = (2m+1) + (3m) - (m-1) = 4m+2$ gives $V_n = k = \frac{3n-1}2$.

Turning it around again:
$$\text{for }n \in \Bbb N, V_n = \begin{cases}6m+2 & n = 4m\\6m+4& n = 4m+1\\6m+5&n=4m+2\\6m+6&n=4m+3\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice answer ... but I don't think you should call a decision tree a "formula", not even a not nice formula.

Comment: @EthanBolker - Actually, all I was trying to do was indicate that I was not disagreeing with your point in my answer. It just fits in a different category than you were referring to.